# InfluxDB2 fields with same name, but different value type

Tags: influxdb-2

I have setup an influxdb2 and want to write data using the line protocol.
My data are CAN-bus messages from different buses.

As measurement I choose the name of the bus (*can1* in the example).
I also choose COB-ID (*MotorBatteryStatus_MS_1* in the example) and format as tags.

"format" could be either

- **raw** which is an integer
- **physical** which is a float
- **enumeration** which is a string

So I want to determine the format of the data by this tag.

The **physical** value is calculated based on the **raw** value which is a natural calculation in this domain. Also the **enumeration** is a string mapping based on the **raw** value.

This means some fields exists with two datatypes in the same set of data.
Here is an example for the current line protocol

```
can1,cobid=MotorBatteryStatus_MS_1,format=raw MotorSpeed=0i,MotorCurrent=0i,MotorVoltage=0i,BatteryVoltage=29i,BatteryCurrent=0i 1675746059287000000
can1,cobid=MotorBatteryStatus_MS_1,format=physical MotorCurrent=0.0,BatteryCurrent=0.0 1675746059287000000
```

For Influx it seems not to be possible to have a field with different datatypes distinguished by the tag choosen.

I also have an influxdb1 where the field name is assembled instead of tags, which is not recommend by influx. So for every data type there is a separate field.

This is an example how the data looks like in influx 1

```
can1,cobid=MotorBatteryStatus_MS_1 MotorSpeed.raw=0i,MotorCurrent.raw=0i,MotorCurrent.physical=0.0,MotorVoltage.raw=0i,BatteryVoltage.raw=29i,BatteryCurrent.raw=0i,BatteryCurrent.physical=0.0 1675746059287000000
```

Is there a workaround or different schema that can be used to have fields with same name and different datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Obvisiously I have to fix my layout for that.

My new layout is like this:

```
can1,cobid=MotorBatteryStatus_MS_1,signal=MotorCurrent raw=0i,physical=0.0 1675746059287000000
```

So I will get more lines as each signal needs to be on a single line and I will only get the fields **raw**, **physical**, **enumeration** instead of the fields with signal names.

I am not sure if I now may run into a high cardinality issue...

Would be perfect if someone can give me his 2 cents on this.